# Slow WiFi Direct connection between Samsung WB250F camera and smartphone

Tags: point-and-shoot, wireless, wifi, tethering

My Samsung WB250F camera can wirelessly transfer photos to a smartphone or a tablet via [WiFi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct). But, though I'm not sure if it's just natural, the transferring seems way too slow to me. It also has a WiFi tethered shooting feature and when I use that feature it infuriates me: it takes about 6 seconds to transfer the photo to my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone before the next photo is snapped.

What's causing the slow tethered shooting process, and is there something that I can do to overcome this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the average file size?

Comment: An image is about 5MBs

Comment: I feel that's pretty normal. Try to click a blank photo and then try to transfer it. This way you would be able to conclude.

Comment: So tethered shooting via WiFi (with a phone) isn't fast like USB?

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi is slow; non-infrastructure Wi-Fi doubly so.  Most devices don't support IBSS (ad-hoc) networking in 802.11n or 802.11ac mode because being a base station requires multiple antennas in those modes.  As a result, if you're tethering over Wi-Fi, you're probably limited to 802.11g speeds (54 Mbps over short distances, slower over longer distances).

With that said, if your numbers are accurate, it should not be **that** slow.  Even over ad-hoc Wi-Fi, in 6 seconds, a camera should be able to transfer a 30-50 MB image.  If it takes that long to transfer a 5 MB image, that's only about 833 kbps, which is appallingly slow even by 802.11b standards.

Technically, the *minimum* speed for 802.11a/b/g/n is 1 Mbps (typically at ~150 feet or so), so if you're getting less than that, you're either getting horrendous packet loss at the very fringes of the radio's range or:

- The software is badly written
- The camera doesn't start transmitting image data until after it finishes writing the photo to the flash card
- Your cell phone is slow
- Some combination of the above

You might try changing Wi-Fi channels if your camera allows you to do so, just in case it is an interference problem.  But otherwise, such poor performance is likely indicative of a design flaw in Samsung's software/firmware, and there's not much you can do about it except complain until they fix it.